# Save HTML table data to a csv file with custom file path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I am currently writing an app using electron, and I'm trying to save the contents of a Html table to a CSV file. 
I tried [this](https://github.com/ZachWick/TableCSVExport), in this way:

```
let $ = require('jquery')
let fs = require('fs')
var dialog = require('electron').remote.dialog
$('#save-file').on('click', () => {
dialog.showSaveDialog({ filters: [{ name: 'csv', extensions: ['csv'] }]}, function (fileName) {
  if(fileName === undefined){
    console.log("Please give a file name!");
  }else{
    var value = $('#data-table').TableCSVExport({delivery:"value"})
    fs.writeFile(fileName, value, function (err) {
    });
  }
});
})
```

It almost satisfy my needs, except for the data are all surrunded by "", which is not what I want.
Then I saw [this](https://github.com/Archakov06/jQuery.tableExport). There are tons of similar ones like this, but they all download automatically once you click the button. 
What I want is when the button gets clicked, it will show up a dialog box to let the user select a file path, then save the file to that position.
Also, I only need the tr(data) to be saved, so exclude the th(headings)
Is there any js library can satisfy my needs?

Appreciated for any guidance!

Comment: So what is it that you are stuck on? Getting a save dialog to appear, or saving the file to csv?

Comment: @unseen_damage Thanks for the reply. I'm stuck on download the csv file to a destination that chosen by the user rather than the default download folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have a user pick their own file location, then the following code is an example of the [showSaveDialog](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/dialog/) method using the csv-write-stream npm package. This is a code snippet and **not a copy/paste fully working example**. The relevant item is the file function plus dependencies:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');
const csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');

function saveFile(){
    const folderLocation = dialog.showOpenDialog({
        title:"Select Save Location",
        properties: ["openDirectory"]
    });

    let writer = csvWriter()
    writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(folderLocation))
    writer.write({hello: "world", foo: "bar", baz: "taco"})
    writer.end()
};
```

You should have the option either way, with showOpen or showSave, to navigate the file structure to pick a folder.

In reference to the handling of csv files, check the following npm packages:

- [csv-write-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream)
- [csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv)
- [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv)

Another cool package for handling CSVs is [handsOnTable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handsontable) for displaying them in your electron app with the look of an excel doc.